# Is it necessary to set up event listener for chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am reviewing a chrome extension and came across with these two doubts which I wanted to clarify.

In the extension that I am reviewing, I get to see a portion of the code in the "background.js" file where a message is being passed to the content scripts using the below lines of code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: !0, currentWindow: !0}, function (a) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(a[0].id, {action: "process_page"}, function (a) {
                       })
                   })
```

1. My first query is with the json-ified message being passed here ({action: "process_page"}). I was not able to locate any associated listener events anywhere in code base for the message (process_page). In fact, the "process_page" seems to exist only once in the entire code base and that too in the background.js file. So, I wanted to know whether a event listener is mandatory for all the chrome.tabs.sendMessage methods or is the event listener an optional one.
2. My second query is - From the Google's chrome.tabs document - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab, I understood that the first parameter of the sendMessage method corresponds to tab id. But, I would like to understand why was it represented as "a[0].id" ?

Any clear pointers or explanations will be really helpful.

Comment: Look for chrome.runtime.onMessage, chrome.runtime.onConnect and the deprecated predecessor chrome.extension.onRequest. Apparently that extension processes any message regardless of its contents.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the reply. Well can you please help me understand what you meant by "Apparently that extension processes any message regardless of its contents".

Comment: Uhm, it means just that. The extension may simply not care about the actual contents of the message, it rather does something on the very fact the message was received, or the sender of the message, or maybe this code is a leftover and does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The event listener is optional: but with no listener, the message sent will have no effect.
2. It is represented as `a[0].id` because the function's argument is an array of `Tab` objects (see [documentation for `chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query). `a[0].id` is the tab Id of the first tab in the array returned by the query.

Comment: You should expand #1 to explain that all listeners are set up to listen to all messages received.  It is up to the listener to decode the contents of the message to determine if it is something which it known how to handle (i.e. explain why `process_page` may not be anywhere else in the code).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed clarifications. Well, do you think there could be any vulnerabilities in keeping the message open in the air without handling them in any of the event listeners.

Comment: @Viman I don't see vulnerabilities, but creating an object to pass it as an argument without need is inefficient.